# What should be done about [explode]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

Explode refers to two concepts.

- In [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), it refers to splitting a string.
- In [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) and [apache-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-spark), it refers to a specific data transformation like well known data transformation concepts: [transpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transpose) or [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pivot). For eg, converting

| Major | Minor |
| --- | --- |
| Face | [Eye, Teeth] |
| Chest | [Heart, Lungs] |

to

| Major | Minor |
| --- | --- |
| Face | Eye |
| Face | Teeth |
| Chest | Heart |
| Chest | Lungs |

- Currently, tag [explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explode) refers to [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) explode in wiki and excerpt, but in practice, it is also used for describing the concept in [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas)
- 85+% of questions(1814/2105) is tagged [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)
- There's another tag [pandas-explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-explode) to refer to the second concept.
- There is also another tag [exploded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exploded), which refers to [explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explode)

##### References:

- [Pandas-explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)
- [Apache-spark-explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode(org.apache.spark.sql.Column))
- [php-explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Even [old 'exploded' questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750427/exploded-deployment-fails-on-jboss-5) are unrelated, they are about exploded WAR/JAR (Java deployment).

Comment: If only this was a burnination request -- the puns! "This tag is about to [explode]!"

Comment: In GIS, it refers to breaking a multipart feature into multiple single part features. Too general a term with only field/context specific uses that don't all mean the same thing. Causes more problems than it solves as a result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a decent argument to be made that "explode" meets the criteria for a tag.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

"Exploding" seems to be a fairly widely-adopted term used across many technologies. These are a handful I found, but I'm sure there are more:

- [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- [Spark](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-explode-nested-array-to-rows/)
- [Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/how-to-analyze-complex-schema#flatten-nested-structures-and-explode-arrays)
- [Arduino](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/any-way-to-do-explode-array-in-arduino/62542)
- [Python](https://devstudioonline.com/article/implode-join-and-explode-split-in-python)
- [Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937024/explode-function-in-hive)

All more or less describe the same process: turning a flat array or string into an n-dimensional data structure.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Software algorithms are [explicitly on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Perhaps not every algorithm is worthy of its own tag, but this concept seems to transcend a particular function or technology. It's a common-enough term and used consistently enough, in my opinion, to be its own tag.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

While I can't envision many posts that could stand with this tag alone, I can imagine some. A question about efficient algorithms related to transforming a 2-dimensional array to a 3-dimensional array would be on-topic and could appropriately be tagged with just [explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explode). (Generally, as with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex), I'd expect to see other tags providing more context, but I don't think it'd be required.)

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

As evidenced by the links above, there seems to be decent consistency across a wide range of technologies, communities and forums. So, yes, at least relative to most other things.

Comment: `turning a flat array or string into an n-dimensional data structure`. If I'm not mistaken, only [php]  wants input as a ``string``. Right?

Comment: Technically speaking, a string is a char array, so it still fits comfortably within the general definition.

Comment: According to the linked documentation the PHP function would be called something like `split()` in most other languages.   It just breaks a string up based on a delimiter; not the data transform that pandas or spark do.

Answer (score 27):

I don't think we need a tag for PHP-specific string splitting at all.

Assuming the Pandas function is tag worthy, I'd say we burn [explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explode) and retag to just [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) or [pandas-explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-explode) as appropriate.

[dataframe-explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe-explode) has been suggested by Henry Ecker in the [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421064/what-should-be-done-about-explode/421066#comment931467_421069) as being able to capture the same concept in a number of other platforms.

Comment: thinking about someone with no context/knowledge seeing "pandas-explode" makes me chuckle

Comment: As a(n alleged) SME in pandas, the pandas-explode _function_ is not tag worthy IMO however the _concept_ that function represents _is_. "Exploding" in this context defines a very specific form of data transformation. This is similar to other transformations like merge, pivot, crosstab, etc. and a dedicated tag makes it very easy to find Q&A about that specific type of data manipulation. Having said that, however, that same "explode" concept is also found in spark. Maybe something like [dataframe-explode] would be better than separate [pandas-explode] and [spark-explode] tags?

Comment: I've seen the same term used with e.g. Excel spreadsheets to mean effectively the same thing.

Comment: Do you have a reference in Excel for explode into rows? I'm not familiar with it and haven't been able to find anything other than [exploding a pie chart](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/explode-or-expand-a-pie-chart-63284b67-22ea-4960-ab1e-0a3895af68ce) which has a rather different meaning. I've also been able to find things like how to implement php style explode style in both google-sheets and Excel but in both cases it's using `split` which is, again, a different concept. @KarlKnechtel

Comment: @HenryEcker While there's no specific name for it in spreadsheets, we do have questions about this repeatedly. Recent questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73983423/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74065157/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74184584/ A generic name for this data transformation tag would greatly help to categorize these questions for duplicate closure.

Comment: Oops, your [pandas-explode].

Comment: I agree with @HenryEcker - While maybe not the most common term, there does seem to be broad adoption of the term "explode" to mean transforming an array into a data structure. E.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/71417/how-to-dynamically-explode-array-type-column-in-py.html

Comment: Why does "explode" within pandas need a dedicated *tag*? How is that not a ridiculous level of overkill vs. just tagging it as [pandas] and then including "explode" somewhere in the title?

Comment: "Dataframe" is not a generic concept, and the term does not have currency across languages or domains. If folks want to enshrine this specific data transformation with a tag, it should not include that bizarre word. It will only deter people who aren't using dataframes from using the tag.

Comment: @jpmc26 The tag makes it easy to categorize questions with the same data transformation concept. We tags like [pivot] to categorize other data transformation concept.

Answer (score 9):

Tldr:

- Rename current [explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explode) => [php-explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-explode)

AND

- Rename [pandas-explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-explode) => [explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explode)

Making the data transformation concept described by [pandas-explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-explode) to be the default concept described by [explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explode) as it is used to describe this concept in [multiple libraries](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421117)

---

No other programming language, except [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), seems to use `explode` to refer to `split`. Most languages use `split` to refer to this concept of splitting string to array. I think [explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explode) shouldn't  be exclusively used by [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php). I agree with [Dan's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421066) that it is better to be burn it altogether. If that's not possible, we can also consider

- renaming [explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explode) => [php-explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-explode).

The data transformation concept described by pandas isn't unique to pandas. At least two different tags([apache-spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-spark) and [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas)) agree on this definition of `explode` making it more universal than php's use of explode. If we have a generic [explode] tag or any other name for this concept, it can be used in any other programming languages/tags like [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r), [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) to describe the same data transformation, which would be useful in  categorizing questions. We can also consider

- Rename [pandas-explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-explode) => [explode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/explode)

A unique/generic name for this data transformation is preferred, so that it can be used in a wide range of softwares/libraries. This is similar to other data transformation tags like

- [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pivot)
- [unpivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unpivot)
- [split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/split)
- [concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concatenation)
- [cross-join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-join)/[cartesian-product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cartesian-product)

Comment: "Rename pandas-explode => explode" this will probably result in a lot of php-explode questions being autocompleted into the wrong tag.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight There isn't many though. 2k questions over decades. Do you have a better name for this concept though?

Comment: 2k over a decade is comparable to many of the tags we're burning; and accumulating that many in the first place says there's no one following the tag to keep it clean.  I'm not the best person to come up with a name since I've never worked with either pandas or spark.  It looks like a form of [denormalization]; but that's a broader topic than just a single action.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight Yes, it would be part of [database-normalization]>part of 1NF.  `2k over a decade is comparable to many of the tags we're burning` While 2k over a decade might seems many, no one is really adding the tag compared to 2013,2014. See [my fork graph here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1660672/stackoverflow-tag-growth-for-explode#graph)

Comment: [dataframe-explode] works for spark, pyspark, pandas, geopandas, etc. I don't know if there's any places where "explode" is used with this meaning _and_ the structure is not referred to as a DataFrame. Easy synonyms if needed like [pandas-explode] -> [dataframe-explode], [pyspark-explode] -> [dataframe-explode]. I don't think the tag is as useful if we used some type of normalisation nomenclature because that's not how their associated official documentation describes these operations and not how experts in those areas would search for this type of transformation.

Comment: @HenryEcker I like it. But I think [sql], [js] or [spreadsheet]s don't use [dataframe] to refer to  their tables or arrays. Still, [dataframe-explode]  is  better than [pandas-explode] as it is more generic. I'd still prefer plain [explode], if possible, for wider coverage of the same concept used elsewhere.

Comment: I'm confused about how to vote on this answer. Would I be voting for `explode` => `php-explode` or `pandas-explode` => `explode`? If you are going to post an answer to a yes/no question, it's helpful if your answer argues one way or the other. If you want to gauge consensus, post more than one answer and let folks vote on the one they prefer.

Comment: @JDB Both. This answer assumes two data transformation concepts: split string to array and split string to make different rows(this creates repitition of contents of other cells, while the former doesn't). [explode] =>[php-explode] AND [pandas-explode]=>[explode]. [Explode] currently has >85% tagged with [php], so it's basically used to refer to what [split] refers to and therefore should not be changed to a different data transformation concept [explode]. So transfer all current questions to [split] and make [pandas-explode] the default [explode], that can be used with every other software.